# Binding Grid ColumnSpan in ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mobile, xamarin.forms, grid

In ListView I want to bind a grid columnSpan and then set it this span in ItemSource object. This is the way I am trying to achieve this but i get:
,,Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I would like to know what is a proper way of doing it and also if it is needed to use any ValueConverter to set span property. 
"Title" Text property is not important for now.

ViewCell:

```
class CustomPerformanceCell : ViewCell
{
    public CustomPerformanceCell()
    {

        var titleLabel = new Label();
        titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty , "Title");

        var resultGrid = new Grid
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        resultGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        resultGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        resultGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

        resultGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        resultGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.DarkGray;

        var ColorBox = new BoxView();
        ColorBox.SetBinding(VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty, "BackgroundColor", BindingMode.Default, new BackgroundConverter(), null);
        resultGrid.Children.Add(ColorBox ,0,0);
        ColorBox.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, "Performance");

    }
}
```

PerformanceCell:

```
public class PerformanceCellItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Performance { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }

    public PerformanceCellItem(string title, int performance ,string backgroundColor)
    {
        Title = title;
        Performance = performance;
        BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

Function for creating it:

```
 public void PreparePerformanceStack()
    {
        PerformanceList = new ListView
        {
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomPerformanceCell))
        };
        ObservableCollection<PerformanceCellItem> cellItems = new ObservableCollection<PerformanceCellItem>
        {
            new PerformanceCellItem("test 1", 2,"#00AA00"),
            new PerformanceCellItem("test 2",  2,"#00AA00"),
            new PerformanceCellItem("test 3",  2,"#00AA00")
        };
        PerformanceList.ItemsSource = cellItems;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColumnSpan` can't be set to `Grid` unless there is a parent grid; if you want to set it to `BoxView` - use `colorBox.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, "Performance")`.

Also, do make sure that the value of `Performance` is >= 1 (otherwise [coerce condition](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Grid.cs#L18) will throw an exception). You don't need a value-converter, as long as source type is either int or a [parse-able string](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Xaml/TypeConversionExtensions.cs#L140).

**EDIT 1** - as per question edit

You need assign `View` property in your custom view-cell

```
this.View = resultGrid;
```

in your constructor `CustomPerformanceCell()`

Comment: Still getting null pointer exceptio. "Performance" is set to 2 so it should definitely work

Comment: Can you share more code on how you are attaching resultGrid to `ViewCell` and then to `DataTemplate` (ListView.ItemTemplate)

Comment: Answer updated! - you will need to set the View property on custom view-cell